# Page object implementation for Winapp Driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, appium, winappdriver

I am using Winapp Driver to control a windows desktop application using java. The automation runs fine but I am looking for a way to implement the Page object model. This is what I am using at the moment.

- Appium
- Winapp
- Driver
- Selenium TestNG

I cannot use the standard Page object of selenium as I cannot get it to work with Winapp Driver it crashes out with Null pointer exception. Does anyone have an example of how this can be achieved.

Comment: Theoretically how successful your page object implementation is should not depend on webdriver implementation. Can you show your problematic code?

Answer (score 1):

A Page Object is simply a design pattern for creating an API for UI manipulation.

[image]

All you have to do it to provide to the page object a way to fetch a low-level UI manipulation tool, such as Selenium. For instance, through a [singleton](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton).

```
class MyTests {

   @Test
   fun test1 {
      val page = FactoryOfPageObjects.newPage("login");
      val homePage = page.login("user", "1234");
      assertTrue(homePage.amILogged());
   }
}

class LogiPage {

   val driver = // You can inject any implementation of Driver here

   fun login(username, password) {
      driver.find("#usernameField").insert(username);
      driver.find("#passwordField").insert(password);
      driver.find("#loginButton").click;
      return new LoggedPage(driver);
   }
}

interface Driver {
   void insert(text);
   void click();
}

class SeleniumDriver implements Driver {...}
class AppiumDriver implements Driver {...}
```

See how above both your **tests and your page objects** have **no idea** about the low-level implementation of which driver you are using at run-time. Meaning that if you already have a working implementation without page objects, you can simply refactor it to isolate all references to your driver to the Driver derivatives.

See [Martin Folwer's post](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) on it for more details.

(Note for a future edit: If you provide the working implementation without the page object, the community can help you to refactor this in order to isolate the low-level details from your tests and page objects).